# ActionController : undefined method action_name for nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, middleware, nomethoderror

I get this error arbitrarily during certain actions in my application. I feel this error is due to `@app.call(env)` in [one of my middlewares](https://gist.github.com/swapnilabnave/77ba6729fdabcd40c43f).

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `action_name' for nil:NilClass):
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:84:in `callback'
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.22/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb:59:in `before'
  vendor/cache/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.22/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:325:in `around'
```

Here's the **[full-trace](https://gist.github.com/swapnilabnave/ccedc2b76f1e1af7f84d)** of exception.

**[Origin](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/actionpack/lib/action_controller/caching/sweeping.rb#L84)** of exception according to trace.

[Similar exception](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/activescaffold/NejdoBn93L4) has been reported on google forum but I am not able to conclude anything out of it.

---

1. Why is this error even raised at first place ?
2. Any solution to avoid it ?
3. Trying to reproduce in a confined environment. Have anybody faced such issue and successfully reproduced it ? (Please share)

Comment: The content of your post isn't that helpful, as the problem is that `controller`is nil, not that there is no `action_name` method. The issue is why no controller is present in the environment where the `Sweeping` module is being used.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. here controller is set to nil, not sure why `controller.action_name`. And this is sporadic.

Comment: I would get rid of that middleware and handle it on the application level instead. I'm trying to figure out why you would use middleware for something like that and coming up blank.